# XAMPP Apache won't start after i added phpPgAdmin alias

Tags: postgresql, xampp, phppgadmin

I want to install phpPgAdmin with XAMPP on Windows. After i did all the steps, my Apache module on XAMPP won't start. I got this error log

```
[Mon Nov 14 16:36:16.661538 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 10612:tid 504] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 14 16:36:16.824335 2016] [core:warn] [pid 10612:tid 504] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Mon Nov 14 16:36:16.924133 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 10612:tid 504] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 14 16:36:17.724645 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10612:tid 504] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 14 16:36:17.724645 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10612:tid 504] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  1 2016 11:09:37
[Mon Nov 14 16:36:17.724645 2016] [core:notice] [pid 10612:tid 504] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Nov 14 16:36:17.724645 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10612:tid 504] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7288
[Mon Nov 14 16:36:18.611254 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7288:tid 584] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 14 16:36:18.796715 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7288:tid 584] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 14 16:36:18.850157 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7288:tid 584] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Mon Nov 14 16:36:22.814454 2016] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 7288:tid 584] AH02538: Child: Parent process exited abruptly. Child process is ending
```

I tried to remove the phpPgAdmin alias from httpd-xamp.conf, and it worked again, but my phpPgAdmin won't work (obviously).
I've uncommented the php_pgsql.dll and php_pdo_pgsql.dll extension at php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

This is my configuration on config.inc.php from phpPgAdmin folder

```
$conf['servers'][0]['host'] = 'localhost';
$conf['servers'][0]['pg_dump_path'] = 'C:\xampp\pgsql\9.3\bin\pg_dump.exe';
$conf['servers'][0]['pg_dumpall_path'] = 'C:\xampp\pgsql\9.3\bin\pg_dumpall.exe';
$conf['extra_login_security'] = false;
```

This is my alias configuration on httpd-xampp.conf

```
Alias /phppgadmin “C:/xampp/phpPgAdmin/”
<Directory “C:/xampp/phpPgAdmin”>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I'm new with XAMPP and PHP, so i don't know what's the problem. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether my answer is not too late, but you just need to change curly braces `“”` in your paths to regular ones `""`, like this

```
"C:/xampp/phppgadmin/"
```

Comment: I didn't see it... Nice catch!

Comment: Wow, that's my fault by copying all configurations instead of typing it...